# How to solve "Failed to instrospect class" in Spring Testing Context?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, integration-testing

Upgrading from Spring Boot 2 to 3 brought some problems with our app.
The following Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-freemarker-email</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3</version> 
    </dependency>
```

cannot be upgraded. So I overrode the classes, and replaced all javax lines/usages with jakarta.
And used BeanProcessor to lazyly init the bean inside the library for the Spring App as follows.

```
    @Component
  public class BeanProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;

        beanDefinitionRegistry
                .getBeanDefinition("defaultEmailService")
                .setLazyInit(true);

    }
}
```

However, when attempting to start the Application Context inside the test files annotating it with @SpringBootTest,
it gives me the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [it.ozimov.springboot.mail.service.defaultimpl.DefaultEmailService] from ClassLoader ....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
```

**Meaning the class *DefaultEmailService*, requires the *javax.activation.DataSource* to be compiled correctly.
I have overriden this bean in the main app, however, tests apparently need the whole code to compile.**

Any suggestions on how to overcome this ? (instead of changing the entire library, we don't have that much time)

Comment: 1. Upgrade the library and post a pull request. The maintainer maybe create a new release. 2. Upgrade the library and create a new custom release in-house.

Comment: Good idea. I have actually overriden most of the classes, so most of the work is done. Thanks man.

Comment: If you duplicate a class (one in the original library and one in your source) with the same name and same package, it will be environment-dependent which class will be loaded by the class loader.

Comment: You can post the comment as answer and I will mark it as correct. I did upgrade the library , posted the PR and now it is released in maven. Thanks a lot for reminding me. The link to the PR: https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools/pull/85

Comment: You solved the problem, so you can post your own solution as an answer.